# How to create an array that in one index has a single element and in the other has another array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

I'm trying to create an object in C# that, when serialized, gives me the following structure:

```
 "should": [
                {
                    "match_phrase": {
                        "customer.document_number": {
                            "query": "01468932128",
                            "slop": 10
                        }
                    }
                },
                [
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "customer.documents.number": {
                                "query": "01468932128",
                                "slop": 10
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "customer.documents.number": {
                                "query": "01468932128",
                                "slop": 10
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase": {
                            "customer.document_number": {
                                "query": "01468932128",
                                "slop": 10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

Realize that the element "should" is an array that in the first index, contains an element of type "match_phrase" and in the second index, contains an array of that same element. That is, it is as if I had an array of size 2, whose first position was an object and the second was an array. How to structure this through an object so that when deserializing you get the mentioned structure? I tried with tuple but it puts an "item1" and "item2" in front of the elements, it doesn't fit.

Comment: Do you mean "when serialized" rather than "when deserialized"?

Comment: Have you validated this JSON?

Comment: Can I suggest that you use the ElasticSearch client to build your queries in code? Well, assuming that's possible in your scenario.

Comment: Thanks John, "when serialized".

Comment: Of course, using the ElasticSearch client would be an option, but I was trying to do something faster and simpler. I have to pass an elasticsearch query via querystring to another system to return me what I need

Comment: In your JSON, you sometimes have `"customer.document_number"` and `"customer.documents.number"`.  Notice that these are different -- sometimes the `_` is a `.`.  Does this inconsistency exist in your JSON, or is this a typo in your question?

Comment: If it's always `"customer.documents.number"` see https://dotnetfiddle.net/poUlLD.  Otherwise, please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but specifically for "array that in one index has a single element and in the other has another array" I'd use a `Dictionary<key, value[]>` if you need lookup, or a `Tuple<value, array[]>`.